# (Using pandas) Database cells do not update outside of function. What to do?

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, cell

So I am trying to fill in missing rows of data using an average of the values in the row above and below it. I am relatively new to coding, so I apologize for any non-concise code.

The following is the function I'm using and some data.

```py
import pandas

def avg_round(a,b,c):
    x = float(round((a + b)/2,c))
    return x

def fill_in_single(c,ro): ##ro signifies to how many digits I need to round the new value to, "c" is the column we need to edit
    m_list = single_missing(c) ##this list has all the rows that are empty in the column "c"
    for i_obj in m_list:
        act_row=i_obj-2 ##I need to do this because the rows are stored as their excel row numbers which is different from the pandas df row number
        prev_row=act_row-1
        next_row=act_row+1
        prev_val=c[prev_row]
        next_val=c[next_row]
        new_val=avg_round(prev_val,next_val,ro)
        df.at[act_row,'{}'.format(c)] = new_val

fill_in_single(Column,0)
print(df.at[2,'Column'])

OUTPUT:
nan
```

```
   Index Column
    0       1
    1       9
    2 
    3       0
```

So when I run this and try to print the value of a supposedly 'updated' column, I get "nan" instead of the new_val. I have run this print command within the function, and it returns new_val. I am really unsure as to what to do?

I have also run the code outside of the function, and it updates the columns properly. So why does the function not work?

Comment: Please provide some sample data. You can copy and paste it from Excel or your jupyter notebook directly into your question with the Code Sample feature. The Code Sample button looks like this { }. You may need to indent by four spaces before each row after pasting in.

Comment: You can `backward fill` and `forward fill` the dataframe and take an average of those two when you `fillna`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

Backward and forward fill the data first like below and take an average of those two columns when you replace the `nan`

```
df['ffill'] = df['y'].ffill()
df['bfill'] = df['y'].bfill()
df['y'].fillna(df[['ffill', 'bfill']].mean(axis=1))
```

Here is the dataset i used

```
d = {'x':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','d','d','d'],
 'y':[1,np.nan,3,1,2,3,1,np.nan,3,1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: The problem is not with averaging, I do not understand why the database does not update outside of the function.